# Is creating a new operation system that is capable of running windows/mac/linux programs legal?

Tags: copyright

If one could create a new operation system that could run/support
all the programs that run on Windows/Linux/Mac or whatever operation system one could find, could Microsoft, the creator of windows, for example, sue the creator of this new operation system?

Comment: Related, Apple drove Psystar out of business circa 2011. Hackintoshes were knock-off hardware that could run OS X. It was more than just x86 compatible hardware. There was some firmware engineering by Psystar that made them compatible. Also see articles like [Apple victorious: Courts deny hackintosher's final plea](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/29/court_denies_final_psystar_plea/): "*Psystar began selling their Mac OS X–capable Open Computer in April 2008, despite the fact that Apple's end-user licensing agreement for Mac OS X clearly forbade running it on non-Apple hardware...."*

Answer (score 1):

It is legal *if* the new operating system you create do not contain any copied source code, and you do not infringe any patents.

However, if your clone becomes extremely successful, that does not protect you from an expensive lawsuit, as is demostrated by [Caldera vs. Microsoft](http://www.embedded-computing.com/embedded-computing-design/software-forensics-lay-ms-dos-cp-m-controversy-to-rest).